# How to draw line programmatically for controls in detail section in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I want to draw line programmatically for controls in the detail section in a crystal report depending on the amount of data in 3 controls without merging these controls together, I have a working code in access and it is running excellent and I want to use the same code in crystal report but I do not know where to put the code and how I can deal with codes like
for each control in detail.controls
My Code in Access is

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
Dim MaxHt As Single
Dim ctl As Control
    MaxHt = Me.Remarks.Height + Me.RemUpdate.Height + Me.Client.Height
 'Get maximum height of any control
        For Each ctl In Me.Section(acDetail).Controls
    If ctl.Height > MaxHt Then
      MaxHt = ctl.Height
    End If
  Next
  'Use maximum height to draw rectangles around each control
    For Each ctl In Me.Section(acDetail).Controls
    Me.Line (ctl.Left, ctl.Top)-(ctl.Left + ctl.Width, MaxHt), vbBlack, B
  Next
End Sub
```

1- I can't find the Detail_Print Event in Crystal Report - I use on Load event (I Don't know if this correct or not)
2- I don't know how to refer to controls in the detail section in crystal report like in Access
example me.Remarks refers to the Remarks Control in Detail Section in Access Report
3- I don't know how to the height or width of control in crystal report field

I checked the web many times and I did not find exact answers
So I need your help

Thanks, Regards

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do it like that. If you draw a line or box in a report section, one of the formatting options is 'Extend to bottom of section when printing'.

Comment: Thanks your reply